# Joining multiple tables with group by throws exception in Entity Framework Core

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I am developing a project with Entity Framework Core. I am using Code First approach. I have the below entities.

**Account**

```
public class Account
    {
        public Account()
        {
            Id = 0;
            IsActive = true;
            AccountRoles = new List<AccountRole>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool? IsSystemAdmin { get; set; }        
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }        
        public int? OrgId { get; set; }

        public IList<AccountRole> AccountRoles { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string UserFullName
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
            }
        }
    }
```

**Role**

```
public class Role
    {
        public Role()
        {
            Id = 0;
            IsActive = true;
            AccountRoles = new List<AccountRole>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
        public int? OrgId { get; set; }   
        public IList<AccountRole> AccountRoles { get; set; }
    }
```

**Account Role**
public class AccountRole
{
public AccountRole()
{
Id = 0;
IsActive = true;
}

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }        
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public Account Account { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I have written a LINQ query to join and group by to get results of all account information with Roles in comma separate. The query is below:

```
var userAccount = (from account in _db.Accounts
                                   join accountRole in _db.AccountRoles on account.Id equals accountRole.AccountId into ars
                                   from ar in ars.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   join role in _db.Roles on ar.RoleId equals role.Id
                                   where
                                      account.UserName == username
                                     && account.Password == password
                                   group new { account, role } by new
                                   {
                                       account.Id,
                                       account.FirstName,
                                       account.LastName,
                                       account.Email,
                                       account.Mobile,
                                       account.UserName,                                       
                                       account.PhotoUrl
                                   } into ag
                                   select new UserAccountInfo
                                   {
                                       AccountId = ag.Key.Id,
                                       FirstName = ag.Key.FirstName,
                                       LastName = ag.Key.LastName,
                                       Email = ag.Key.Email,
                                       Mobile = ag.Key.Mobile,
                                       Username = ag.Key.UserName,                                       
                                       PhotoUrl = ag.Key.PhotoUrl,
                                       Roles = string.Join(",", ag.Select(x => x.role.Title))
                                   }).FirstOrDefault();
```

When call the API through Postman, I found the below errors. Can anyone help me to solve the problem.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression
> 'GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: new {
> Id = a.Id,
> FirstName = a.FirstName,
> LastName = a.LastName,
> Email = a.Email,
> Mobile = a.Mobile,
> UserName = a.UserName,
> PhotoUrl = a.PhotoUrl  },  ElementSelector:new {
> account = EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: Account
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: account
> IsNullable: False
> ,
> role = EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: Role
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: role
> IsNullable: True  } ' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may
> indicate either a bug or a limitation in Entity Framework. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed
> information.    at
> CashFlow.Services.AccountService.ValidateLoginAsync(String username,
> String password) in D:\Workspace\My
> Projects\CashFlow\CashFlow-API\SourceCode\Libraries\Services\AccountService.cs:line
> 77    at Web.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginModel model) in
> D:\Workspace\My
> Projects\CashFlow\CashFlow-API\SourceCode\Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line
> 51    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Comment: It has nothing in common with table joins, the problem (not supported) is the `string.Join` method

Comment: Then, how can I get the role names in comma separated value

Comment: In general you can't. because no such method exists in SQL.

Comment: And why on the earth are you doing all these manual joins, group by etc. -  your model classes have all the necessary navigation properties to produce the result with simple `Select`. The only thing you have to change is `UserAccountInfo.Roles` type from `string` to `List<string>` or something like that.

Comment: Ok. I got your point

Comment: Is the below query OK? I have write it different way.

Comment: I could swear I answered this same question already this week. Read what Ivan wrote again. You do not need all those joins in the linq code, EF does all that for you.

Comment: Can you give me the link of one of your answer?

Comment: If you're using code first, AND you either (1) follow the naming conventions for tables, primary and foreign keys, or (2) use the fluent API and/or data annotations to define the relationships between the tables, THEN Entity Framework will take care of the joins for you. That's kind of the whole point in using Entity Framework. If you're going to hand code the joins in the code, there's really no point using EF.

Comment: I suggest you work through this [tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx). It won't take more than an hour or so and it might answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the query in below way and it works fine.

```
var userAccount = (from account in _db.Accounts
                                   join accountRole in _db.AccountRoles on account.Id equals accountRole.AccountId into ars
                                   from ar in ars.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   join role in _db.Roles on ar.RoleId equals role.Id
                                   where account.UserName == username && account.Password == password
                                   select new UserAccountInfo
                                   {
                                       AccountId = account.Id,
                                       FirstName = account.FirstName,
                                       LastName = account.LastName,
                                       Email = account.Email,
                                       Mobile = account.Mobile,
                                       Username = account.UserName,
                                       PhotoUrl = account.PhotoUrl,
                                       IsActive = account.IsActive,
                                       Roles = role.Title
                                   }).ToList().GroupBy(x => new
                                   {
                                       x.AccountId,
                                       x.FirstName,
                                       x.LastName,
                                       x.Email,
                                       x.Mobile,
                                       x.Username,
                                       x.PhotoUrl,
                                       x.IsActive
                                   }).Select(y => new UserAccountInfo
                                   {
                                       AccountId = y.Key.AccountId,
                                       FirstName = y.Key.FirstName,
                                       LastName = y.Key.LastName,
                                       Email = y.Key.Email,
                                       Mobile = y.Key.Mobile,
                                       Username = y.Key.Username,
                                       PhotoUrl = y.Key.PhotoUrl,
                                       IsActive = y.Key.IsActive,
                                       Roles = string.Join(",", y.Select(a => a.Roles))
                                   });
```